# Jsoup select a random one (1) from a class of div

Tags: java, jsoup

In the page there are multiple divs of the same class like this one:

```
<div class="author-quote">
    <a href="#">Maldives</a>
</div>
```

Each div has an `<a>` tag and the text within the `<a>` tags are different.

now in my Java method:

```
private String get() throws InterruptedException{
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            Elements elements;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(WEB_URL).get();

                    elements = doc.select("div.author-quote");
                    value.add(elements.text()); // added the whole class
                    latch.countDown();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
                }
            }// end run
        });

        thread.start();
        latch.await();
        return value.get(0);
    }
```

And it gets all the texts from divs of the class `author-quote`. Here is the output:

```
Pakistan Maldives Lichtenstein China Panama
```

But I just want one of them, a random one. How do I do it?

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**: some `<a>` tags contain multi-word terms like Republic of Ireland and Guinea-Bissau and some have symbols like Dominican Rep.

**Update**: I am able to separate them using some string manipulations. But I hope I can do it with Jsoup's Element select tools.

Comment: I'd assume the whole output is stored as the first element within the `value` ArrayList? is this correct?

Comment: @Aominè yes. I do that because to get a value out of a thread you have to declare a final data structure. The whole output is stored in value.get(0)

Answer (score 0):

you can split the `value.get(0)` by the delimiter `" "` (thus yielding an array of strings) then use a [`Random#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) to index into the array and pick a random `String` object.

```
...
...
...
String[] tempArray = value.get(0).split(" ");
return tempArray[new Random().nextInt(tempArray.length)];
```

**UPDATE**

As per your post update, another alternative solution would be from the web page side, you can surround all the divs that have a `class` attribute of `author-quote` within one main `div` element (if not already done) then select this parent `div`, thus enabling you to iterate over the `parentDiv` ChildNodes and collect their text individually then add to the `ArrayList`.

```
private String get() throws InterruptedException{
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        Element parentDiv;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(WEB_URL).get();

                parentDiv = //getTheParentDivSomehow()
                for (Node child : parentDiv.childNodes()) {
                     Node tempNode = child.childNodes().get(0);
                     if (tempNode.childNodes().get(0) instanceof TextNode) 
                           value.add(((TextNode) child).text());

                }
                latch.countDown();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
            }
        }// end run
        });

        thread.start();
        latch.await();
        Collections.shuffle(value);
        return value.get(new Random().nextInt(value.size()));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not disclosing this, but some `<a>` tags contain multi-word terms like `Republic of Ireland` and `Guinea-Bissau` and some have symbols like `Dominican Rep.`. Can we do something in the Jsoup `Element` selection?

Comment: @DylanCzenski I've not used jsoup before but after some research I've come with an updated answer, if it doesn't work please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String get() throws InterruptedException{
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        Elements elements;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(WEB_URL).get();
                //returns a list of Elements
                elements = doc.select("div.author-quote"); 
                //use a random number and get the Element at that index to select one div element at random
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomIndex = random.nextInt(elements.size());//returns a random number between 0 and elements.size()
                value.add(elements.get(randomIndex).text()); // add only the text of the random Element
                latch.countDown();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
            }
        }// end run
    });

    thread.start();
    latch.await();
    return value.get(0);
}
```